# Brick breaker not removing bricks from array list

Tags: java, android

I am working on a brick breaker game for Android. Currently, I am using an ArrayList for the bricks. I need to remove each one individually from the list and the screen upon collision with the ball. Currently, when the ball collides with the very last brick in the array (bottom right corner), half of the array gets removed (every other brick). Upon colliding with it again, it removes a few more bricks randomly, but none of this is even close to what I need.

Here is my code. `brick` is an object within the Bricks ArrayList.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= bricks.size(); i++) {
    if (RectF.intersects(brick.rect, ball.rect)) {
        bricks.remove(bricks.get(i));
        ball.dy = -ball.dy;
        score += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: `i <= bricks.size()` in the `for` seems wrong. Use `<` instead of `<=`?

Comment: didn't affect anything

Comment: yes i have done that.

Comment: maybe its a problem with your intersects

Comment: Calling `bricks.remove()` while iterating `bricks` in ascending order seems a bad idea.

Comment: i think it is. but i'm not sure what. not entirely sure how to reverse through the loop.

Comment: `for(int i=bricks.size()-1; i>=0; i--)` ?

Comment: Why use `brick.rect` instead of `bricks.get(i).rect` in your `if` line? Is the `if` line supposed to be not directly dependent on `i`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `Iterator`:

```
for (Iterator<Brick> it = bricks.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Brick brick = it.next();

    if (RectF.intersects(brick.rect, ball.rect)) {
        it.remove();
        ball.dy = -ball.dy;
        score += 10;
    }
}
```

Or you can just reverse original code to delete bricks from the end.